# 80s/90s sci-fi horror movie - parasite (alien?) caterpillar

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, virus

When I was young, perhaps around early, or mid, or maybe even late 90s, I watched around the first 30 minutes of what I remember was a low budget American sci-fi horror flick. It was broadcast on our local TV in Serbia, so it could be from the early 90s but also late 80s as well.

I don't remember much except that there was this weird (alien? virus? parasite?) life form that would somehow end up inside living humans, growing until it made them really sick. It obviously involved some scientists researching the phenomenon. I think it was happening in a regular US city on planet Earth, and I remember this gross scene of the life form, now already kinda big, maybe like 10 inches long, looking like a big whitish caterpillar of sorts, leaving a woman's body through her mouth.

Before it finally went out and ended in the scientist's dish, you could see it poking through the neck from within, looking for the exit, gaaaa super gross! Which is why we changed the channel and I haven't seen more of it.

Comment: Did the woman survive having the alien leave her, or did it choke her to death on the way out?

Comment: @DavidW I think she survived but she was in a bad shape

Comment: This makes me think of Shivers from 1975

Comment: Also sounds vaguely like the X-Files episode [Firewalker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewalker_(The_X-Files)) - but that was a parasite that ended up bursting out of people's throats and killing 'em.

Comment: @DannyMcG it looks a bit too old, but i will download and check

Comment: @JonClements fits the era but i dont think thats it, just checked the episode out

Comment: @DannyMcG nope not it

Comment: How about 'Night of the Creeps'? That was from the late eighties and had similar worm creatures to Shivers

Comment: Were they like black slugs about a foot long and very fast?

Comment: @DannyMcG no, they were whitish, and slow...This caterpillar-like phase was only a phase in their development I think, but I might be wrong about that. They were definitely growing inside their host, which would culminate in their exit through the mouth, as I explained. It doesn't seemt to be Night of the Creeps , there werent dark in color, and not slug-like, nor there were this party atmosphere.

Comment: Actually, now that i think about it, it might be later in the 90s too, so I will edit the question. Really not sure about the timing -  I just don't want to discard potential movies coming out later.

Comment: It's not an exact match, but I'm getting hints of Shivers.

Comment: @moopet nope not it but thanks

Answer (score 5):

I am 100% sure this is ***[Unknown Origin](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114795/)*** (1995). I’ve been looking for this for years and I’m certain that’s the movie after watching a trailer of it tonight.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alien_Within):

> *The Alien Within* is a 1995 horror science fiction film directed by Scott P. Levy and starring Roddy McDowall, Alex Hyde-White, Melanie Shatner, Don Stroud, and Richard Biggs. It was also known as *Unknown Origin*.

From IMDB:

> Trapped under 2500 ft. Of crushing pressure, an underwater research team is invaded by an unknown mind-controlling alien. Terror turns to paranoia as the team members turn on each other, unable to discern friend from foe.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve your answer by describing the movie to  explain how it matches the question.

Comment: Note that the OP said they think the film was set in a regular US city. According to the Wikipedia page, _Unknown Origin_ is mostly set within an underwater mining platform.

Comment: haha you've been looking for the same movie as me? wow. might be, some of the scenes look very familiar. would have to try to track it down to see it

Comment: @Spaceploit Did you track it down to find out for sure if this answer is right or not?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a 2006 film "Slither." A comedy/horror/sci-fi.
Director-James Gunn
Writer-James Gunn
Stars Nathan Fillion, Elizabeth Banks, Michael Rooker
A small town is taken over by alien parasites turning the residents into zombies.

Comment: _Slither_ has somewhat similar parasites in it, but is there a scene where a white-ish, caterpillar-like creature crawls out of a woman's mouth? I don't recall such a scene myself, though it's been a while since I last watched it.

Comment: Nope definitely not it. This is definitely an older movie than Slither, I would say at least 10 years or more.

Answer (score 0):

Reminds me of movies Hidden(1987) and Hidden 2(1993)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think either one of those might be the correct movie, i.e. the ways in which they match the one described in the question. It'd help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.

Comment: they look like fun but dont seem to be it. is there a scene as I described in either of the two?

Comment: I bet I remember some kind of whiteish parasite coming out of a mouth, but it was a man’s mouth.

Comment: I've seen both _The Hidden_ films, and while they do feature parasites entering and exiting people's mouths, I don't recall the specific scene described in the question, with one exiting a woman's mouth onto a scientist's dish.